# Not gettin correct Days diff betweentwo dates of different year

Tags: java, datetime

I am using java code to find the days diff. between two dates let say '12/27/16' and '01/01/17'

Code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy");

Date d1= format.parse("12/27/16");
Date d2=format.parse("01/01/17");

long diff = d1.getTime()-d2.getTime();
long diffDays= diff / (24*60*60*1000);
```

But when I print diffDays then i am getting 352 days rather 6 days

Comment: You want to calculate the difference based on `d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()`, not the other way around.

Comment: @nbokmans i am ok with any way as far as getting the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `d1`, you'll see:

```
Wed Jan 27 00:12:00 CET 2016
```

That's definitely not what you put in. The reason is that your format string is wrong: `m` means minutes, not month. The correct format is `"M/d/y"`.

And, as @nbokmans already noted, `d1 - d2` is backwards and should be `d2 - d1`.

See also the [documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot. It worked. Just changed with upper case M

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas and @nbokmans answered, the dates are the wrong way round (but the code can be easily changed to ignore this). However, Java has a lot of convenience classes for dealing with times and dates that are not well known. I would replace the explicit calculation with one of the following:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    Date d1 = format.parse("12/27/16");
    Date d2 = format.parse("01/01/17");

    long days1 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
    long days2 = Duration.between(d1.toInstant(), d2.toInstant()).abs().toDays();
    long days3 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1.toInstant(), d2.toInstant());
```